# Listeners keyset is a differrent one in the onMessageReceived method than in the rest of the class

Tags: android, firebase, listener, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use listeners in the onMessageReceived method, but the keyset in the data map is a different one (different object address) than the one used in the class... you'll find the relevant code below:

```
private String token;
@Singleton
private final Map<EventType, List<FCMListener>> listeners;

public enum EventType {
    //...
}

public PushApiConnection() {
    super();
    this.token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    this.listeners = new HashMap<>();
}

public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    if (data.size() > 0) {
        for(String key: data.keySet()){
            final String value = data.get(key);
            switch (key) {
                case "registrationEvent":
                    List<FCMListener> registrationListeners = this.listeners.get(EventType.registrationEventEntity);
                    if(registrationListeners!=null)
                        for (FCMListener listener : registrationListeners) listener.onReceiveMessage(value);
                    //here the keyset is empty
                    //this is called after the register method
                    Log.d(TAG, this.listeners.keySet().toString());
                    break;
                case "loginEvent":
                    List<FCMListener> loginListeners = this.listeners.get(EventType.loginEventEntity);
                    if(loginListeners!=null)
                        for (FCMListener listener : loginListeners) listener.onReceiveMessage(value);
                    //here the keyset is empty
                    //this is called after the register method
                    Log.d(TAG, this.listeners.keySet().toString());
                    break;
                case ...:
                    //some more cases
                default:
                    Log.d(TAG, key + " -> " + value);
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown key: \"" + key + "\"");
            }
        }
    }
}

public void register(EventType eventType, FCMListener listener) {
    if (!this.listeners.containsKey(eventType))
        this.listeners.put(eventType, new ArrayList<>(1));
    List<FCMListener> listeners = this.listeners.get(eventType);
    listeners.add(listener);
    //here the keyset has two (different) events inside
    Log.d(TAG, "listeners "  + this.listeners.keyset().toString());
}
```

If more information is needed I will be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the firebase messaging service and the app created an own instance of the onject. That is why we had two different instances and the listener did not work. I hope this helps people who encounter the same problem.
I tried to fix it using an intent, but the context is null when the constructor is called, I am loogking for other alternatives at the moment (storing it to a file may be the solution, although a dirty one in my opinion). I' ll post back once I found a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably fix your code by setting `listeners` as **static variable.**

Also, I am not understanding how you are going to use this code.
Which code is registering the listener in the `listeners` HashMap?

Probably it's easier if you use an alternative like:

- just invoke the method you want to invoke
- send a Broadcast https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html
- (maybe a LocalBroadcast https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)